Voltage-controlled oscillator problem
I am trying to simulate this sine wave VCO:

I set the control voltage with the R14/R15 voltage divider, but for some reason the frequency does not seem to depend on the control voltage.


What do I miss here?

Where did you find the schematic? Source? Also, hopefully, there will be a design discussion with it that should be carefully read. If not, if it is just a pasted schematic without any discussion, then you are asking us to analyze this circuit for you and determine whether or not it can do what you say it can do and if so tell you what you did wrong or if not then tell you why this circuit doesn't work and provide a solution that does work. That's an awful lot to ask. I'll leave that to others. (My experience is with relaxation types, not harmonic. At a guess, this looks like relaxation.)

It's clear that the frequency does change, but only by a few percent. But it's an odd circuit -- where did you get it? For one thing, there's no DC path through Q5, so it isn't clear what it's good for. It appears to be some sort of phase-shift oscillator, and it isn't clear why its frequency should be sensitive to the bias level of Q2, which is basically what Q1 is changing.


I set the control voltage with the R14/R15 voltage divider, but for some reason the frequency does not seem to depend on the control voltage.

Your simulation does not vary the control voltage, so you cannot conclude that "the frequency does not seem to depend on the control voltage".
Replace that voltage divider with a voltage source that varies, say, from 0.5V to 1.0V over a long period of time, say, 100ms.  You can use a PWL or PULSE in Spice for that purpose.

Well, OP has posted two schematics/plots, one where the voltage divider at the Q1 is 80/10 ohm, and one where its 10/80 ohm. And they're absolutely showing different frequencies - I won't say obviously, but if one takes the time to count some peaks, they are definitely different.

@MrGerber Well spotted.  I saw the resistors 10/80 ohm but did not noticed their positions swapped. Sneaky way changing the voltage. :-) Perhaps you should post an answer.  Cheers.


What do I miss here?

What you miss are the subtle details.
The frequency does vary between your two posted plots, but maybe not as much as you anticipated.
The first plot (R14=80 ohm, R15=10 ohm) has a hair under 12 periods in 2 ms - just under 6 kHz

The second plot (R14=10 ohm, R15=80 ohm) has pretty close to 25 periods in 4 ms - ~6.25 kHz



...  but for some reason the frequency does not seem to depend on the control voltage.

Made with microcap v12.
The VCO should be ok. Use a control voltage > ~ 1 V.
Use a square wave, for example, and measure frequency.
You can note that frequency vary very "slightly".

